# htaccess redirect to https only one file

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I'd like to redirect all request to the index.php script (not a additional http request, only internal).

When the request url is checkout.html there should be a redirect to the https file.
All other request should be http.

HTTPs to HTTP works correctly, but HTTP to HTTPS there occurs an additional request to index.php.

**Here are my htaccess file:**

```
# Redirect http checkout.html to https
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} checkout\.html [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

# Redirect https to http (excluding checkout.html)
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !checkout\.html [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

# all script to index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^.*\.html|.php$ /index.php [L]
```

**HTTPS to HTTP (e.g. _http://.../basket.html):**

- 301: redirect _https://.../basket.html to _http://.../basket.html
  (correct)
- 200: http response basket.html

**HTTP to HTTPS (e.g. _http://.../checkout.html)**

- 301: redirect _http://.../checkout.html to _https://.../checkout.html (correct)
- 301: redirect _https://.../checkout.html to _http://.../index.php (not correct)
- 200: http response index.php

What is going wrong??

Comment: `https://...checkout.html` doesn't match either the first or second set of conditions, so it gets picked up by the third set of conditions.  When you redirect from `http://...checkout.html` to the secure version, that secure page request also goes through all these .htaccess conditions.

Comment: I don't understand why there is a 301-redirect when I open `https://..checkout.html` to the index.php (third condition) and when I open `http://...basket.html`  the redirect is only internal to index.php (also third condition)

Comment: The 3rd condition isn't a 301 redirect.  It's just saying to execute index.php; there'll always be a request for that file. `http://...basket.html` doesn't satisfy either the 1st or 2nd set of conditions, so just gets handled by the 3rd set, i.e. also just to execute index.php

Comment: But why is there a 301-redirect to the index.php when the request is `https://...checkout.html`?? (example: https://www.websaar.de/checkout.html)

Comment: If I request http://www.websaar.de/checkout.html I get a 302 redirect.  This combined with the fact https://www.websaar.de/checkout.html gives a 301 redirect indicates to me that what's really happening isn't what's in the .htaccess in your question.  Either a different .htaccess file is doing the redirects, or there's something else going on at the webserver.

Comment: FYI, this is almost certainly a security mistake. You will need SSL everywhere after you initialize a session or set any other cookies, not just on the checkout page, to preserve the safety of your session key. I recommend you read OWASP's materials on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} checkout.html [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !checkout.html [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !index.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule .* index.php [L] 

</IfModule>
```

I need to add the following line to the "https on" condition:
`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !index.php [NC]`